# App Crashes When I Try To Evaluate A PostFix Expression In The Calculator

Tags: android, postfix-notation

> I am trying to make a basic calculator in android and for evaluation i am using a **Infix to Postfix** conversion i am taking my input from the **EditText** and converting it into a string and passing it in the Evaluation method.....but when i run it and press the **Equals Button to evaluate my result my app crashes** below is the code and the logcat.

```
public class Evaluate {

String[] evalStack = new String[100];
String[] stackPostfix = new String[100];
char[] operatorStack = new char[100];
int top,j,k,i,top_operator_stack;
String number="";

public void InfixToPostfix(String s){

    k=0;
    top=s.length();
    top_operator_stack=0;
    operatorStack[top_operator_stack]='(';

    for(i=0;i<top;i++)
    {
        char extract = s.charAt(i);
        if(extract!='+'&&extract!='-'&&extract!='*'&&extract!='/'&&extract!='^'&&extract!='('&&extract!=')')
        {
            number=number+extract;
        }else if(extract=='+'||extract=='-'||extract=='*'||extract=='/'||extract=='^')
        {
            if(number!="")
            {   
                stackPostfix[k++]=number;
                number="";
            }
            operatorStack[++top_operator_stack]=extract;
            for(j=top_operator_stack-1;operatorStack[j]!='(';j--)
            {
                int currentOperatorPriority,previousOperatorPriority;
                currentOperatorPriority = returnPriority(operatorStack[i]);
                previousOperatorPriority = returnPriority(operatorStack[j]);
                if(previousOperatorPriority>=currentOperatorPriority)
                {
                    stackPostfix[k++]=""+operatorStack[j];
                    operatorStack[j]=operatorStack[j+1];
                    top_operator_stack--;
                }
            }
        }else if(extract=='('){
            if(number!="")
            {
                stackPostfix[k++]=number;
                number="";
            }
            operatorStack[++top_operator_stack] = '(';
        }else if(extract==')'){
            if(number!="")
            {
                stackPostfix[k++]=number;
                number="";
            }
            while(operatorStack[top_operator_stack]!='(')
            {
                stackPostfix[k++] = "" + operatorStack[top_operator_stack--];
            }
        top_operator_stack--;
        }
    }
}

private static int returnPriority(char ch){
    switch(ch){
    case '+':return 1;
    case '-':return 1;
    case '/':return 2;
    case '*':return 2;
    case '^':return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}

public String EvaluatePostfix(){

    top=0;

    for(int i =0;stackPostfix[i]!=")";i++)
    {
        if(stackPostfix[i]!="+"&&stackPostfix[i]!="-"&&stackPostfix[i]!="*"&&stackPostfix[i]!="/"&&stackPostfix[i]!="^")
        {
            evalStack[top++]=stackPostfix[i];
        }else{
            String sym = stackPostfix[i];
            double top_element = Double.parseDouble(evalStack[top]);
            double next_top_element = Double.parseDouble(evalStack[top-1]);
            switch(sym){
            case "+" :evalStack[top--]=""+(next_top_element+top_element);
                      break;
            case "-" :evalStack[top--]=""+(next_top_element-top_element);
                      break;
            case "/" :evalStack[top--]=""+(next_top_element/top_element);
                      break;
            case "*" :evalStack[top--]=""+(next_top_element*top_element);
                      break;
            case "^" :evalStack[top--]=""+(Math.pow(next_top_element, top_element));
                      break;
            }
        }
    }
    return evalStack[0];
}
 ![LogCat When App Crashes][1]}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from the log cat.

Comment: Not Enough reputation to post pics here lol :(

Comment: But It shows a null pointer exception

Comment: You could copy and paste it instead.